# Identify which apps on ipad belong to another account for which I do not have the password?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

For historic reasons I have some apps installed on my iPad that were  legitimately downloaded using another account than the one I am using now.  I do not have the current password for said account, so I cannot provide it when I occasionally am prompted for it.

The iPad synchronizes against an iTunes instance running on my MacBook which I have full control over.

I have no idea which apps cause this, and I would like to identify them so I can get uninstall them and stop being prompted.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This script run on my Mac having iTunes showed the account for each IPA-file.

```
for f in ~/Music/iTunes/Mobile\ Applications/*.ipa;  do (echo "$f" ; unzip -p "$f" "iTunesMetadata.plist" |  plutil -p - | egrep -i "\"(itemName|artistName|AppleID)\"" ) |  perl -e 'while (<>) { if (m!^/!) { chop; $fqn=$_; } if (m/"(.+)" => (".+")/) { $e{lc($1)}=$2; } } print "$e{\"appleid\"}\t\"${fqn}\"\t$e{\"itemname\"}\t$e{\"artistname\"}\n";'; done|sort|less
```

It is an adaptation of the script shown in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256278/3157