# How to find MinimumOSVersion of all purchased iOS apps in iTunes?

Tags: macos, itunes, applications, ios

I have many purchased iOS apps in my iTunes on macOS. I have an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1.2 that cannot be upgraded to any upper iOS due to lack of compatibility. Some of apps in iTunes were downloaded in my iPhone 4 and then transferred to iTunes, these apps are compatible with my iPhone 4; But other apps were downloaded directly in iTunes need minimum version of iOS greater than 7.1.2. I want to find these incompatible apps with my iPhone 4.

A naive solution is to sync all apps with my iPhone 4 and look in error message that will list incompatible apps. Is there any fast solution to find all of those apps to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed Walt Stoneburner's [script](https://www.wwco.com/~wls/blog/2012/11/18/list-itunes-apps-by-purchaser/) that I used to answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256278/117407) to list MimimumOSVersion of apps located in iTunes library. Run This script in terminal:

```
for f in ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/*.ipa; do
    (echo "$f" ; unzip -Z1 "$f" | egrep -i ".app/Info.plist$" | \
        awk '{ print length($0) " " $0; }' | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | head -n1 | \
        xargs -I file unzip -p "$f" file  | \
        plutil -p - | egrep -i "\"MinimumOSVersion\"" ) | \
        perl -e 'while (<>) { if (m!^/!) { chop; $fqn=$_; } if (m/"(.+)" => (".+")/) { $e{lc($1)}=$2; } } print "\"${fqn}\",$e{\"minimumosversion\"}\n";'; \
done
```

It will list apps like this:

```
"/Users/username/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications/app1.ipa","7.0"
"/Users/username/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications/app1.ipa","8.0"
"/Users/username/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications/app3.ipa","7.1"
...
```

If you want the output in a file you can save the script in a file (`minimum.sh` for example) then run this command in the terminal:

```
$ sh minimum.sh > output.csv
```

Then open `output.csv` with Apple Numbers and sort the table with second column. Minimum iOS versions required are now observable.